# Convert List<Object> to Map<Integer, List<Object>> using Java 8 Streams API

Tags: java

I have `List<Object>`, and I want to convert it into `Map<Integer, List<Object>>` where key is the size of the list and value is the list itself using java 8 streams api. I can do it using Java 7 as

```
Map<Integer, List<Object>> map= new HashMap<>();
map.put(list.size(), list);
```

But how to do it using Java 8.

Comment: Same code will work in Java 8. Why do you want to involve streams? This looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: I know, same code will work in Java 8, just want to know, if it can be done?

Comment: Why streams? There is no _streaming_ or _iterating_ involved in your code.

Answer (score 1):

That should be just

```
Stream.of(list)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(List::size, Function.identity()));
```

---

But *why* do you want to do this? It's pointless. If you had written this and I were to review your code, I would definitely reject this.

The Streams API is not some magical key to just solve everything. The Streams API is built to operate on *streams of elements*, in a functional manner.

Just stick with the way you mentioned in your post.

Comment: *The Streams API is not some magical key to just solve everything.* That statement alone is worth the upvote!